# Entity Framework 4: Math.Sin()-function

Tags: entity-framework-4

is there an possibility to call the Math.Sin()-function in a Linq To Entites (Entity Framework 4) -Query?

I've read, that the current Entity Framework 4 doesn't implement this function.

Maybe there's a workaround to this solve problem?

(I don't want to invite all entries in the memory.)

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Not near my development machine right now, but System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.Sin() doesn't work?

Comment: Could you mark one of the answers below as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several functions that (usually) have obvious SQL counterparts, like `Math.Sin` can't be used directly in Entity Framework queries. Presumably this is because they can't be reliably translated to different SQL implementations. A ton of MSSQL-specific functions are, however, exposed as static methods in the class `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions`. They throw exceptions if you call them directly, but are translated into the proper SQL if used in a LINQ query.

See [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/efdesign/edm-and-store-functions-exposed-in-linq) about the magic that's happening under the covers (namely the `EdmFunction` attribute).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's impossible to call `Math.Sin` in a LinqToEntities query (or Entity SQL query).

The only way to accomplish this without resorting to retrieving all objects first, is to write a SQL query that does what you want and call it via [`ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorequery.aspx). This isn't as bad as it sounds because you can still [get back typed results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769.aspx).

---

EDIT: After reading the other answers, it appears that it **is** possible to call these types of functions (`SqlFunctions` contains 44 functions with various overloads). I leave my original answer as is because it's another way of achieving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to use such function starting with EF4. In EF4, EF team introduced SqlServer functions that can be consumed in linq. You should alway consider using canonical functions cuz they are database agnostic and every vendor should convert those functions to store specific equivalent. However when such functions are not available, you can resort to SqlServer namespace (ESQL) or SqlFunctions for linq

from l in db.Locations
select SqlServer.Sin(l.Latitude) + SqlServer.power(l.Longitutde)

I cover several of these options in my functions chapter in my book. Specifically you can look at 11-10 recipe Calling database function in esql
11-11 Calling Database Function in LINQ